# Navigation is not transition to full screen when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have got a basic navbar that looks like a mobile navigation menu, but when click it does nothing and I wish it to expand out like the image below. I have tried searching on google, youtube and even on here for a solution, but I am still getting nothing.

What I want to get:

[image]

My Code:

```css
.Xs7C {
  top: var(--privacy-banner-height);
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  z-index: 250;
  color: #fff;
  padding: var(--base-pixel-size) var(--padding-sides);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 74px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

._22gu._3T1K {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

._3Xun {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), transparent), url(../img/global/nav-bg/206t.jpg);
}

._22gu {
  top: var(--privacy-banner-height);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 10px));
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header class="Xs7C   ">
  <div class="_23pr">
    <a aria-current="page" class="active" href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="x_u7">
    <a aria-current="page" class="active" data-gtm-category="Mega Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav" data-gtm-label="Main Logo" href="/">
      <div class="_3LFU "></div>
      <div class="euJN _3Auj"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="_2K8A">
    <div class="_2LLW _1SuQ">
      <a class="_1ebF" target="_blank"></a>
      <nav class="_2vCM _3T1K">
        <a href="/auth/scauth-login">Sign In</a>
        <a href="/auth/signup">Join Social Club</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="_3GNz"></div>
  <div class="_19fX"></div>
</header>
<nav class="_22gu  _3Xun">
  <div class="_1PXj">
    <div class="_2FhW">
      <form class="gQLW">
        <button type="submit"></button>
        <input autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="Search Fierce Games" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="jBdq">
      <a data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Newswire" href="/newswire">Newswire</a>
      <a data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Games" href="/games">Games</a>
      <a data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Videos" href="/videos">Videos</a>
      <a data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Downloads" href="/downloads">Downloads</a>
      <a href="https://support.examplegames.com?redirect_lang=en_us" data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Support" to="https://support.examplegames.com?redirect_lang=en_us" target="_blank">Support</a>
      <a href="https://socialclub.examplegames.com/" data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Socialclub" to="https://socialclub.examplegames.com/" target="_blank">Social Club</a>
      <a href="https://socialclub.examplegames.com/example-games-launcher" data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Launcher" to="https://socialclub.examplegames.com/example-games-launcher" target="_blank">Launcher</a>
      <a href="https://www.examplewarehouse.com/" data-gtm-category="Site Nav" data-gtm-action="Main Nav Click" data-gtm-label="Warehouse" to="https://www.examplewarehouse.com/" target="_blank">Warehouse</a>
    </div>
    <footer class="_3mkF ">
      <div class="_6Jbp">
        <div class="_1Hh3 ">
          <button>
                  <i></i>
                  <span>English</span>
                </button>
          <div class="_15Lf">
            <div class="k43J">
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/">English</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/de/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/de/">Deutsch</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/fr/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/fr/">Français</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/it/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/it/">Italiano</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/jp/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/jp/">日本語</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/ru/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/ru/">Pусский</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/es/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/es/">Español (España)</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/mx/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/mx/">Español (México)</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/br/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/br/">Português</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/kr/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/kr/">한국어</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/zh/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/zh/">中文（简体）</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/tw/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/tw/">中文（繁體）</a>
              <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/pl/" to="https://www.examplegames.com/pl/">Polski</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_1Wst">
          <a href="mailto:mouthoff@examplegames.com" to="mailto:mouthoff@examplegames.com" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Mouthoff email">Mouthoff</a>
          <a href="mailto:PR@examplegames.com" to="mailto:PR@examplegames.com" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Press email">Press</a>
          <a data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Corporate Info" href="/corpinfo">Corporate</a>
          <a data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Privacy" href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
          <a data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Cookies" href="/cookies">Cookies</a>
          <a data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Legal" href="/legal">Legal</a>
          <a href="https://www.examplegames.com/careers" to="https://www.examplegames.com/careers" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Careers">Careers</a>
          <a href="https://socialclub.examplegames.com/settings/email" to="https://socialclub.examplegames.com/settings/email" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Club" data-gtm-label="Manage Subscription Account">Subscribe</a>
          <a data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="CCPA Link" data-gtm-label="View CCPA Info" href="/ccpa">Do Not Sell My Info</a>
        </div>
        <div class="_3gRX">
          <a href="https://twitch.tv/examplegames" to="https://twitch.tv/examplegames" target="_blank" class="piLt" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Twitch"></a>
          <a href="https://instagram.com/examplegames" to="https://instagram.com/examplegames" target="_blank" class="_1RrR" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Instagram"></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/examplegames" to="https://twitter.com/examplegames" target="_blank" class="_3Kl1" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Twitter"></a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/examplegames" to="https://www.youtube.com/examplegames" target="_blank" class="_2bGH" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="YouTube"></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/examplegames" to="https://www.facebook.com/examplegames" target="_blank" class="_1mwQ" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action=" Social Click" data-gtm-label="Facebook"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a js code. Example:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="index.html" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <a onclick="openNav()">open</a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't work as It just gives me text that says open and when clicked, then it gives me the Mobile nav symbol. Where as I wand to click on the mobile nav symbol and then the nav appears, like the image above.